# Prestashop 1.7 - City field as dropdown or autocomplete

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am using Prestashop 1.7 and I need to change the city input field.

I have a billing software that only allows me to use predefined cities. So I have created a table ps_cities with the entries (id an city name).

I know how to write a dropdown or a autocomplete script, but I do not know where to change the input type in the Prestashop files.

On the 1.6 version you have the input field in a theme file, but somehow I fail to find in the new version.

Answer (score 1):

In PrestaShop 1.7.7.X I've created a module that includes some new (and cool!) hooks like showing below. I consider this one a good option because it will be easier to maintain in the next PrestaShop releases.

Some assumptions here: I created a relationship model `CityAddress` with two fields id_city and id_address and a `City` model with fields like name, id_state, id_country, also I continued using `Address::city` string name for compatibility.

```php
/**
     * @see /classes/form/CustomerAddressFormatter.php#L156
     * @param array $param [
     *   @var array $fields
     * ]
     */
    public function hookAdditionalCustomerAddressFields($params)
    {
        ($params['fields']['city'])->setType('hidden');

        // New field
        $formField = $params['fields'];
        $formField = (new FormField())
        ->setName('id_city')
        ->setLabel($this->l('City'))
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->setType('select')
        ;

        // If an address already exits, select the default city
        if (Tools::getIsset('id_address')) {
            $address = new Address(Tools::getValue('id_address'));

            if (!empty($address->id_state)) {
                $cities = City::getCitiesByIdState((int) $address->id_state);

                if (!empty($cities)) {
                    foreach ($cities as $city) {
                        $formField->addAvailableValue(
                            $city['id_city'],
                            $city['name']
                        );
                    }

                    $id_city = CityAddress::getIdCityByIdAddress((int) $address->id);
                    $formField->setValue($id_city);
                }
            }
        }

        // Add the id_city field in the position of the city field
        $keys = array_keys($params['fields']);

        $search = 'city';
        foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == $search) {
                break;
            }
        }

        $part1 = array_slice($params['fields'], 0, $key + 1);
        $part2 = array_slice($params['fields'], $key + 1);

        $part1['id_city'] = $formField;

        $params['fields'] = array_merge($part1, $part2);
    }
```

This one to validate the field:

```php
/**
     * @see /classes/form/CustomerAddressForm.php#L123
     * @param array $param [
     *   @var CustomerAddressForm $form
     * ]
     */
    public function hookActionValidateCustomerAddressForm($params)
    {
        if (empty(Tools::getValue('id_city'))
        || empty(Tools::getValue('city'))) {
            return false;
        }

        $form = $params['form'];

        $idCityField = $form->getField('id_city');

        $idCity = (int) Tools::getValue('id_city');
        $cityObj = new City($idCity);

        $city = pSQL(Tools::getValue('city'));

        if ($cityObj->name !== $city) {
            $idCityField->addError(sprintf(
                $this->l('Invalid name in field id_city %s and city %s'),
                $cityObj->name,
                $city
            ));

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

And the submitted field:

```php
/**
     * @see /classes/form/CustomerAddressForm.php#L153
     * @param array $param [
     *   @var Address $address
     * ]
     */
    public function hookActionSubmitCustomerAddressForm($params)
    {
        /** @var Address */
        $address = $params['address'];
        $address->save();

        if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($address)) {
            throw new PrestaShopException($this->l('Address object error while trying to save city'));
        }

        // If address has a previous value then update it
        $cityAddress = CityAddress::getCityAddressByIdAddress((int) $address->id);
        $city = City::getCityByNameAndIdState($address->city, $address->id_state);

        $cityAddress->id_city = $city->id;
        $cityAddress->id_address = $address->id;
        $cityAddress->save();
        
    }
```

It is possible if you have this line in the `additionalCustomerAddressFields` hook:

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/form/CustomerAddressFormatter.php#L150

For previous version I included `['fields' => &$format]` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all form fields of the Front Office in your theme's `/templates/_partials/form-fields.tpl` file